# How to import a Gradle module from a different root project?

Tags: android, gradle

I have two separate Gradle projects. The first is an Android project and the second is a library project with multiple modules.

```
AppRootProject
-> app
```

```
LibraryRootProject
-> lib-feature
-> lib-core
-> lib-utils
-> lib-sample-app
```

Is there a clean way to set up the dependencies like so:

- `app` depends on `lib-feature`
- `lib-feature` declares API dependencies on `lib-core`, `lib-utils` and third party libraries.

`LibraryRootProject` is a separate repository and I would normally depend on the remote artifact. But I need to make changes and test locally to the library and test locally.

Currently the only way I can work out how to set this up locally is with the following in `app`'s `build.gradle`:

```
implementation files('../../LibraryRootProject/lib-feature/build/outputs/aar/lib-feature-release.aar')
implementation files('../../LibraryRootProject/lib-utils/build/outputs/aar/lib-utils-release.aar')
implementation files('../../LibraryRootProject/lib-core/build/libs/core.jar')
implementation 'com.third.party.lib:1.0.0' // transitive api dependency of lib-feature
```

Currently I have two problems:

1. I need to declare all the transitive dependencies from `lib-feature` in `app`'s `build.gradle`
2. I need to build the `LibraryRootProject` separately

Comment: In `app/settings.gradle` you can add: `project(':lib').projectDir = new File("/path-to-project/LibraryRootProject/lib-feature")` then you can add the `lib` module as dependency. For the transitive dependencies you should try.

Comment: Check out [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)!

Answer (score 0):

As replied in a comment, you should check out [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro) that are designed exactly for that use case.

It is as simple as doing:
`./gradlew --include-build path/to/LibraryRootProject <tasks>`